# Serialize/deserialize FLAGS in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to serialize my tensorflow configuration flags so they're stored in a file and I can reload them later.
The json module objects to serializing the 'Flag' type. I tried constructing a new dictionary using the flag `name` and `FLAGS.__flags[name].value` but some flags are nested dictionaries.
It seems like I'm trying to reinvent the wheel.  Is there a concrete example of serializing/deserializing the config?

`TypeError: Object of type 'Flag' is not JSON serializable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try something like this:

```
def flag_to_dict(FLAGS):
    if tf.__version__ == '1.5':
        flag_dict = FLAGS.flag_values_dict()
    else:
        flag_dict = FLAGS.__flags
    return flag_dict
```

However, in some more recent TensorFlow version, I still got the same error! In that case the custom serializer (together with code above) solved the issue:

```
class TfAwareEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, tf.flags.Flag):
            return obj.value
        else:
            return super(TfAwareEncoder, self).default(obj)
# ...
json.dump(flag_dict, open_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True, cls=TfAwareEncoder)
```